# jQuery $.post doesn't work with when function(response) added

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following js function

```
function remove() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("button").click(function(e) {
            var buttonHnd = jQuery(this);
            jQuery.post("script.php", {
            nume_client: jQuery("#nume_client").val()
            adresa: jQuery("#adresa").val(),
            comanda: jQuery("#comanda").val(),
            locatie: jQuery("#locatie").val(),
            istoric: jQuery("#istoric").val(),
            observatii: jQuery("#observatii").val()
        }, function(response) {
            alert("ok")
        },
        function(data) {
            buttonHnd.closest('tr').remove();
        });
    });
});
}
```

When i remove **function(response)** the script works, it removes the row. but i also want to add it to the database. In the `script.php` file i have only the mysql query with response headers.

The second issue is that my remove button works only on the second click but only after all rows are removed.

Can anyone help with the database problem?

You can find here the [script.php](http://www.segasiauto.ro/tmp/script.txt) file

**EDIT**

there was a line missing from this post. the file contains the correct code.

Comment: What, you mean putting `document.ready` in a function? Maybe he knows something we don't know.

Comment: @Madmartigan - T. J pretty much did catch all issues.

Comment: And `buttonHnd` out of scope in the third function. Though I'm not sure that will ever do anything. That's why I think something has been lost in copying and pasting, this it too messed up, there must be some ajax code missing.

Comment: @Madmartigan: Oh, I caught it, I just forgot to put in the comment for it until I went back with a best guess restructure. :-)

Comment: @Madmartigan - That's not "fixing a problem", that's "guessing what the OP meant". T.J. did in fact fix the OP's problem appropriately.

Comment: As it turns out the code snippet was incomplete and it makes sense now. I still don't understand what would happen when you call a function that's guts are wrapped in `document.ready`. Will it run or not? Presumably, the document is already ready, and that's an event. I would think it would never run unless it acts as a closure and the function was called before `document.ready`

Answer (score 1):

**Update**:

As of your recent edit adding in the missing line of code, the original answer below no longer applies. There's still a syntax error (missing comma after `nume_client: jQuery("#nume_client").val()`), but I'll assume that's a copy-and-paste error. Adding in the comma makes it syntactically valid.

What your code is doing is, every single time you call `remove`, it's asking jQuery to run a function when the document is "ready". That'll mostly be fine as long as you never call `remove` *before* the document is ready (or only do so once), because afterward jQuery will just call the function immediately.

What that function does is set up a click handler on every `button` element on your page. And then (if you call it again) it sets up the handler *again*, so now there are two handlers on every `button` on the page, each of which will try to do the same thing when the button is clicked. If you call it a third time, you'll have *three* handlers on every `button` on the page, all trying to do the same thing when any button is clicked.

Once you've called `remove` at least once, all `button`s on the page will respond to a click by trying to do the `post` and (on success) remove the nearest containing `tr`.

Here's what I think you mean to do:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("button").click(function(e) {
        var buttonHnd = jQuery(this);
        jQuery.post("script.php",
            {
                nume_client: jQuery("#nume_client").val(),
                adresa:      jQuery("#adresa").val(),
                comanda:     jQuery("#comanda").val(),
                locatie:     jQuery("#locatie").val(),
                istoric:     jQuery("#istoric").val(),
                observatii:  jQuery("#observatii").val()
            },
            function(data) {
                buttonHnd.closest('tr').remove();
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Changes:

1. Completely remove the function `remove`, so this code executes as soon as it's encountered on the page, setting up the function to be called when the DOM is ready. Make sure that you have this code *after* the `script` tag that includes jQuery. And you'll want to modify the code that was calling `remove` to not call it.
2. Remove the second function, leaving the third. The [signature for `jQuery.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) accepts a URL, the data to post, a function, and optionally a data type string. You were passing a function for the last parameter, which isn't (as far as I know) supported, and almost certainly wasn't what you wanted to do. :-)

That will still hook this up to *every* button on the page, which you probably don't want. Instead, you probably want to make that selectors more specific (e.g., using an ID, use a structural selector, use a class, etc.; with jQuery you have [lots of choices](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for how to narrow that down).

Although that will work, it will also leave dangling event handlers on the `button` elements that get removed when the `tr` is removed. For dealing with dynamic tables, you probably want to use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/). `delegate` hooks the event on a container element, but only fires your code if the event was generated by an element matching a selector you give it. There's only one event handler, but it acts a lot like there's a handler on the elements that match the selector. `live` is basically `delegate` using the document root as the container.

In your case, I'd probably use `delegate` on the `table` element with a selector along the lines of `button[name="remove"]`. Example HTML:

```
<table id='theTable'>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Blah blah blah</td>
    <td><button name='remove'>Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Blah blah blah</td>
    <td><button name='remove'>Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

With that example HTML, then:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#theTable").delegate('button[name="remove"]', 'click', function(e) {
        var buttonHnd = jQuery(this);
        jQuery.post("script.php",
            {
                nume_client: jQuery("#nume_client").val(),
                adresa:      jQuery("#adresa").val(),
                comanda:     jQuery("#comanda").val(),
                locatie:     jQuery("#locatie").val(),
                istoric:     jQuery("#istoric").val(),
                observatii:  jQuery("#observatii").val()
            },
            function(data) {
                buttonHnd.closest('tr').remove();
            }
        );
    });
});
```

You don't have to use `name`, so long as you can identify which `button` elements should respond to the click in this way. If **all** of the `button` elements in the table are remove buttons, just use `jQuery('#theTable').delegate('button', 'click', function...`.

**Addition to the update**:

You asked me to take a look at the script.php file. Sorry, I'm not much of a PHP-head, but FWIW, the meat of the script is:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `baza`.`tabel` (`1`, `2`, `3`) VALUES ('".$arr['adresa']."', '".$arr['nume_client']."', '".$arr['comanda']."')";
```

Observations:

1. You're not doing anything to escape the values in `$arr['adresa']`, etc. There are two big problems with not doing that:

   1. The query will break if (for instance) `$arr['adresa']` or any of the other fields has a `'` in it.
   2. You're leaving yourself wide open to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Read the [php.net page on SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and how to avoid it.
2. Do the columns in `baza.tabel` *really* have the names`1`, `2`, and `3`? That's a very strange table structure. Normally I'd expect to see columns with names like (for instance) `nume_client`, `adresa`, and `comanda`.

---

**Original answer**:

You have a number of problems in that code:

```
function remove() {

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery("button").click(function(e) {

            var buttonHnd = jQuery(this);

            nume_client: jQuery("#nume_client").val()
         // ^-- Here you're creating a label, I suspect you were trying to create a property

            adresa: jQuery("#adresa").val(),
         // ^-- And here

            comanda: jQuery("#comanda").val(),
         // ^-- And here, I expect this one's actually a syntax error,
         //     check your browser's JavaScript console for errors

            locatie: jQuery("#locatie").val(),
         // ^-- And here

            istoric: jQuery("#istoric").val(),
         // ^-- And here
            observatii: jQuery("#observatii").val()
         // ^-- And here
        }, function(response) { // <== Here you're passing a second function into `click`
            alert("ok")
        },

        function(data) { // <=== Here you're passing a *third* function into `click`
            buttonHnd.closest('tr').remove();
        });
    });
});
}
```

At a *guess*, I'd say you probably want something like this:

```
function remove() {

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery("button").click(function(e) {

            var buttonHnd = jQuery(this);

            jQuery.post(some_url_here,
                {
                    nume_client: jQuery("#nume_client").val(),
                    adresa: jQuery("#adresa").val(),
                    comanda: jQuery("#comanda").val(),
                    locatie: jQuery("#locatie").val(),
                    istoric: jQuery("#istoric").val(),
                    observatii: jQuery("#observatii").val()
                },
                function(response) {
                    buttonHnd.closest('tr').remove();
                }
            );
        });
    });
}
```

...but you don't want it all wrapped up in that `remove` function, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: my code works fine. i have no syntax errors. the problem is that the data isn't added to the database and i tried to get a response. a smaller issue is that when i remove all the rows, and add a new one the button has to be clicked twice.

Comment: @sebastian: Now that you've edited your question to add in the missing code, it still has at least one syntax error (missing comma after `nume_client: jQuery("#nume_client").val()`), but I'll assume that's a copy-and-paste error. Adding in the missing comma makes the code syntactically valid, but there are still logical errors. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @T.J. thank you for your explicit answer. i modified and it works with only 1 click. i have only 1 button on page so that wont be a problem. the others are `input type=button`. the problem with giving a specific name is a bit harder because i get new rows when data is sent through a websocket so i can't counter the rows properly. as I've said I tested the script but no data was added into the database? Can you please check the `script.php` file?

Comment: @sebastian: I'm not much of a PHP-head, but I did add some observations.

Comment: @T.J. thanks for your answer. i got it to add to the database, but i keep getting redirected how can i run the `script.php` file without leaving the page?

Comment: @sebastian: It sounds like the buttons are `type='submit'` buttons. If so, you want to hook the form's `submit` event and cancel it. (Cancelling the `click` event on the buttons won't do it reliably cross-browser, it has to be the `submit` event on the form.) So basically `$('#theFormID').submit(false);`. That's a shortcut for `$('#theFormID').bind('click', function() { return false; });`. The `false` there is a shortcut for `function() { return false; }` that jQuery supports, more [in the docs](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

Comment: @sebastian: *(continuing)* I said above that cancelling the `click` event on the `button` isn't sufficient cross-browser. That's certainly true of `input type='submit'` elements, but I can't immediately prove that it's true of `button` elements: http://jsbin.com/ujoxa6 Or perhaps it's a jQuery thing, something the library is doing for us. As long as you test with your target browsers, it may be that cancelling the `click` is sufficient. But cancelling the `submit` **definitely** works. :-)

Comment: @T.J. i've read that ajax is the only method that can post scripts without refresh or redirect. tried that too, also tired $.ajax with your suggestions aoubt `$('#theFormId').submit(false);`, script runs with no errors but data isn't added to the database.

Comment: @sebastian: That suggests to me that your markup isn't quite right. The way you're getting your field values (`jQuery("#adresa").val()` and such) requires that the fields have those `id` values (e.g., `id='adresa'`), not `name` values. Perhaps that's it. Re ajax: `jQuery.post` **is** an "ajax" call (specifically, an ajax call using the POST HTTP method).

Answer (score 0):

This will break all your scripts (possibly) because is not formatted properly

```
            nume_client: jQuery("#nume_client").val()
            adresa: jQuery("#adresa").val(),
            comanda: jQuery("#comanda").val(),
            locatie: jQuery("#locatie").val(),
            istoric: jQuery("#istoric").val(),
            observatii: jQuery("#observatii").val()
```

its useless like that u should do it like so or atleast thats what I think you are trying to do.

```
var obj = {nume_client: jQuery("#nume_client").val()
            adresa: jQuery("#adresa").val(),
            comanda: jQuery("#comanda").val(),
            locatie: jQuery("#locatie").val(),
            istoric: jQuery("#istoric").val(),
            observatii: jQuery("#observatii").val()
};
```

**EDIT**
anyways I think what you are trying to do is an ajax of some kind

```
 jQuery("button").click(function(e) {
        var buttonHnd = jQuery(this);
        var data =  {
          nume_client: jQuery("#nume_client").val()
          adresa: jQuery("#adresa").val(),
          comanda: jQuery("#comanda").val(),
          locatie: jQuery("#locatie").val(),
          istoric: jQuery("#istoric").val(),
          observatii: jQuery("#observatii").val()
       };
       $.ajax({
             url: 'script.php',
             type: 'post',
             data:data,
             success: function (response){
                   alert('ok')
             },
             error:function (){
                  //in case you get a 500,404 error etcc 
             }
       });
    },
    function(data) {
        buttonHnd.closest('tr').remove();
    });
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. i tried your script and for one click of the button i get 2-3 alerts. also the row isn't removed. this is what i am trying to do: build a table using DOM, complete some text boxes, then click a button add the values to the database and remove the row. with my script the row is removed but, the data isn't added to the database. can you please also check the script.php file?

Comment: why didnt you says so in the first place ? ok I will add something  else in a minute